# How can I set a Table View Controller to my own view controller subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, subclass, viewcontroller

I have a Table View Controller with the title `Class` (like a school course).
I entered a new file > UIViewController subclass template > .. Name: `ClassViewController` and  subclass of: `UITableViewController`...

After that, in the mainstoryboard I clicked on my `Class` table view controller and in the Identity Inspector, under custom class,  I tried to set its Class to `PlayersViewController`. That is the essential step for hooking up a scene from the storyboard with your own view controller subclass.

But it doesnt give me that option in the drop down, and if I just type it in, it doesn't save.

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Surely you should be setting it to ClassViewController, not PlayersViewController? Your subclass is ClassViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the view you are trying to hookup in the identity inspector is a TableView? In case it is, you should be able to open it and type in the name of your class (if your class is a UITableViewController)

You said you were trying to hook up the PlayersViewController, but the UITableViewcontroller subview is ClassViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you like to develop a dropdown, try using existings frameworks or apps like VPPDropdown[link](https://github.com/vicpenap/VPPDropDown)